# Get variable from inner function

Tags: java, android

I created an android app by using firebase database. This app needs to refresh date at once daily basis.

so I am getting date(long) from firebase database which I update from my admin. Date taking very important role in my app so I can't use device time to this.

So the point is I have created a class which gets this date from firbase database as shown below

[Firebase Datebase img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k40Mq.png)

```
   public class time {

public String admin_time;

    public String getAdmin_time() {
        return admin_time;
    }

    public void setAdmin_time(String admin_time) {
        this.admin_time = admin_time;
    }

    public time() {
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("admin_time/admin_time")
                .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.exists()) {
                            setAdmin_time(Objects.requireNonNull(snapshot.getValue()).toString()); // i have set snapshot value to admin_time 
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Then I am trying to get `admin_time` value from another class

```
    time time = new time();
    String a = time.admin_time;  // trying to call direct String
    String b = time.getAdmin_time(); // trying to get value by using getter
    myTextView.setText(a + " " + b);
```

but getting both values null
How can I get `admin_time` to another class?

Comment: Firebase value event is not received values yet that's why you are getting null. You need to wait till value received.

Comment: i can get value in onDataChange() currectly ..but i cant access it from another class, this is the main problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value

Comment: @MaheshMahadar I understand you are getting value in onDataChange() , but you are calling getAdmin_time() method before it set data. please refer below answer you may find helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `interface` to provide `time` once it is fetched

```
interface TimeListener{
     void onTime(String time);
}
```

Then in your `time` class (which should be `Time` ideally) pass the `interface` and get the `time` back when it's ready

```
  public class Time {
    
        private String admin_time;
    
        public String getAdmin_time() {
            return admin_time;
        }
    
        public void setAdmin_time(String admin_time) {
            this.admin_time = admin_time;
        }
    
        public time(TimeListener timeListener) {//<-adding listener to constructor
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("admin_time/admin_time")
                    .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                                setAdmin_time(Objects.requireNonNull(snapshot.getValue()).toString()); 
                               timeListener.onTime(admin_time);//<-passing time back
                            }
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                        }
                    });
        }
    }
```

then while accessing do below

```
Time time = new Time(new TimeListener{
  @Override
  public void onTime(String t){
     //use t here for admin_time
  }
}
```

Comment: @rajn sk sir i have a query can i use t value out of the onTime() ? by using getter and setter

Comment: you can create a global variable and assign `t` to it, but it won't be set unless `onTime` method is called

Comment: i call new Timer in onStart() ... then i create a globle variable ..and asigned it onTime ... i getting null ....